# Email Form write to .xlsx NOT .xls

Tags: php, xlsx, xls

I have an email form that has a few variables and I need that information to write to a .xlsx file.

I have never written to that kind of file before but have written to a .xls file hundreds of times.

The code below does not work, it will create the file but nothing is written to it.

Can I please have some feedback on how to get this structure to write to a .xlsx file?

```
$Course = $_POST["Course"];
$CourseNumber = $_POST["CourseNumber"];
$MemberFee = $_POST["MemberFee"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];

$db.="$Course\t";
$db.="$CourseNumber\t";
$db.="$$MemberFee\t";
$db.="$Email\t";
$db.="\n";

$dbout=fopen("tls-member.xlsx","a+");
fwrite($dbout, $db);
fwrite($dbout,$message);
fclose($dbout);
```

Comment: Did you try [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) it was designed for this purpose

Comment: Otherwise look at [phpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)